# JQGrid virtual scrolling not working

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, scroll, virtual

I have a simple JQGrid with this code:

```
jQuery("#MyJQGrid").jqGrid({
        url: dataUrl,
        datatype: "json",
        height: 550,
        width: 1180,
        colNames: columnNames,
        colModel: columnModel,            
        rowNum: 100,
        mtype: "POST",
        gridview: true,
        sortname: "Times",
        viewrecords: true                       
    });
```

My JQGrid loads correctly the first 100 rows but it is not loading any more pages. I read and copied the JQGrid page example one time and another and I cannot solve this issue. Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have more data, you should enable paging or scrolling. You can use paging by adding `pager: "#pager"` in the grid options and add `<div id="pager"></div>` below your table tag. And if you like to have automatic scrolling, just add `scroll: true` in your code. Remember, if you set `scroll: true`, paging will disable automatically. Obviously, you need to handle paging in your server side by adding `offset` and `limit` to your sql query in both cases.